# Retriving mail from contacts crashes if there is no mail set in iPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts

I am trying to retrieve email from the contacts. I am able to retrieve it successfully, but if there are no email set for a person and if I try to retrieve their contact then the app crashes.

I want to check whether the mail is there or not for particular contact and display an alert if there is no mail set for the contact. How can I achieve it?

Comment: backtrace?  crash log? console messages? any clues at all??

Comment: Sounds like your consumer isn't handling a nil case properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by finding the cfindex value it returns 1  if mailid is available and 0 if no mail id is not available.

```
CFIndex emailCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(mail1);
```